# Flask: 400 BAD REQUEST

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, юнит-тесты, flask

Здравствуйте. Есть такая проблема. Пишу простенький сайт на Flask и есть вот такие функции.
views.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Blueprint, flash, redirect, render_template, request, url_for, session
from flask_login import login_required, logout_user
from db_connect import User
from tweeter.tweeter.extensions import login_manager
from tweeter.tweeter.public.forms import LoginForm
from tweeter.tweeter.user.forms import RegisterForm
from tweeter.tweeter.utils import flash_errors
import datetime

blueprint = Blueprint('public', __name__, static_folder='../static')


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    result = User.select().where(User.id == int(user_id))
    if len(result) > 0:
        return result[0]


@blueprint.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(username=request.data.username, password=request.data.password)
        if form.validate():
            form.user.is_authenticated = True
            login(form.user)
            flash('You are logged in.', 'success')
            redirect_url = request.args.get('next') or url_for('user.members')
            return redirect(redirect_url)
        else:
            flash_errors(form)
    return render_template('public/home.html', form=form)


def login(user, remember=False, fresh=True):
    session['user_id'] = user.id
    session['_fresh'] = fresh
    session['_id'] = user.id
    if remember:
        session['remember'] = 'set'
    return True


@blueprint.route('/logout/')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash('You are logged out.', 'info')
    return redirect(url_for('public.home'))


@blueprint.route('/register/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterForm(request.form, csrf_enabled=False)
    if form.validate:
        User.create(login=form.username.data, password=form.password.data, created=datetime.datetime.now())
        flash('Thank you for registering. You can now log in.', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('public.home'))
    else:
        flash_errors(form)
    return render_template('public/register.html', form=form)
```

И к функциям home, logout, register нужно написать тесты.
unit_test.py:

```
class TestFlask(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.app.testing = True
        self.client = self.app.test_client()

    def test_home(self):
        # 200 OK
        request = self.client.get('/')
        print(request)
        # 400 BAD REQUEST
        post = self.client.post('/', data=dict())
        print(post)
        #
        post = self.client.post('/', data=dict(username='login', password='password'), follow_redirects=True)
        print(post)
        return
```

Как видно из кода, я делаю запросы. Первый запрос статус 200, второй 400 а как сделать чтобы третий запрос возвращал адекватный ответ. Не 400 BAD REQUEST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ в документации. Оказывается надо указать ещё один ключ:
csrf_token. Закомментировать строку на форме в шаблоне:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```

и отключить эту защиту в views.py, forms.py. Далее пример:

```
from extensions import csrf_protect

@csrf_protect.exempt
def home():
```

И убрал инициализацию из файла app.py:

```
def register_extensions(app):
    assets.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    cache.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    # csrf_protect.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    debug_toolbar.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    return None
```

Забыл указать что я использовал готовый проект flask cookiecutter.